# остановить растягивание сайта

Tags: html, css

Есть сайт test.ru с адаптивным дизайном (разные отступы, эксклюзивные для разрешения элементы). Последнее из css-свойств:

```
@media all and (min-width: 1920px) {
...
}
```

Проблема собственно в том, что несмотря на наличие специальных свойств сайт теряет всякую привлекательность уже после 2560+ и увеличение отступов тут не сильно помогает.
Соответственно вопрос: как ограничить масштабирование сайта после 1920 (чтобы на любом большем разрешении показывалась версия для 1920 (то есть чтобы сами элементы росли))?

Comment: Почитайте про `width`, `max-width`.

Comment: @igor-r не помогает, при любой из возможных конфигураций (выставлении любого из значений для :root и body) как бы после контента возникает дыра белая

Comment: @igor-r вот так: https://sun9-25.userapi.com/c854424/v854424308/1f6976/IrCDL3tjIFQ.jpg

Comment: Приведите код. По картинкам можете сами продолжать дебажить.

Comment: @igor-r iccmiu.ru , всё там (да отладка на уже работающем серваке, всё равно всем пофиг)(сейчас значения ширины не стоят)

Comment: поместить содержимое в `.container { max-width: 1920px; width: 100%; marin: 0 auto}`

Comment: @HamSter https://sun9-6.userapi.com/c857732/v857732781/1800f5/nObJnt-kLrk.jpg ваш вариант к вот такому приводит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@media (min-width: 1920px) and (max-width: 99999px) {
...
}

Comment: Ну так а в свойства что написать? :before {content: Воспользуйтесь монитором с разрешением не выше fullHD} ? 

Comment: 1. CSS расшифровывается как "Каскадная таблица стилей", главное слово тут "Каскадная". Если не понятно слово "Каскад", читайте его как "Водопад" =) Вы же пытаетесь с конца свойства описать.
2. Для CSS есть единицы измерения не только абсолютные, но и относительные: https://tuhub.ru/refs/css/length Рисуйте блоки относительно размера страницы.
3. в свойства можно писать формулы, например width: calc(100% - 20rem) или font-size: calc(1em * 2);

Comment: вот что будет если заменить px на em: https://ibb.co/TmxtmH2

Comment: а, ага, спасибо, буду экспериментировать. К относительным величинам в блоках я конечно привык, а вот тексты пока не делал.

Answer (score 0):

Поместить содеоржимое с белым фоном в контейнер

```
.container { max-width: 1920px; width: 100%; marin: 0 auto}
```

Для меню и подвала в контейнер поместить не само меню, а обернуть его содержимое

```
<body>
<div id=head><div class=container>меню</div></div>
<div class=container>текст</div>
</body>
```

Comment: https://sun9-49.userapi.com/c857732/v857732400/178c9c/PC2D9_fa-14.jpg после добавления указанных свойств контейнеру "body"

Comment: почему боди то?)

Comment: ну тот же футер прижался при помощи для <html> height: 100% и для <body> min-height: 100% . Плодить кучи контейнеров тоже не кайф, когда базовые есть

Comment: они не лишние. Вы вот сайи на webpack посмотрите там на один элемент по 5 дивов

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.wrapper{
width:100vw;
}
.content{
margin:0 auto;
max-width:1920px;
z-index:2;
}
@media screen and (max-width:1920px){
.wrapper{
max-width:100%;
}
}
</style>

<body>
<siv class=wrapper>
<div class='content'>
здесь контент
</div>
</div>
```